# Getting 409 error on form submit

Tags: web, e-commerce, http-error

So am getting a 409 Conflict with Failed to load resource error. Happens when i click on a form submit of a generic Java web application.

On click of the button there is no application log shows up, just the following error shows up and the process ends. This log is from browser console.
[image]

What are the possibilities for such an issue? Any help/suggestion will be really helpful.Help on internet was not much helpful.
Interestingly this is very intermediate i.e. it happens for a device and the next time you won't see it, comes back from grave again in few hrs or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I have not received this error, but based on your problem statement, it seems you could be having trouble with a file lock on your server.  If you are attempting to call a resource that is loaded in another tool like an IDE, then it is possible the file is locked and the server is raising this error.

You may only receive this error if your server is in development mode vs production mode.  Production mode will cache the file and not result in a conflict.

Here is a link that partially explains the problem.

[HTTP Error 409 Conflict](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E409.html)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for trying to help. This link is the first thing which i read and comes as soon as you do a google search. Wanted better insight on this error. I think it might be something to do with caching. I am still investigating this.